# Pushing UIViewController crashes

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have the following code pushing a UIViewController. This code is a target method that gets executed when a `UIButton` is pressed:

```
-(void)pushNavigationController
{
    ParameterListerViewController *plvc = [[ParameterListerViewController alloc] init];    
    UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:plvc];    
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    plvc.numberOfParameters = [[numberOfTrialsField text] intValue];

    NSLog(@"about to push the navigation controller");

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nvc animated:YES];
}
```

It gets until the NSLog statement, but after that, the view controller never gets pushed and the app just crashes. Here is the header file of `ParameterListerViewController`:

```
ParameterListerViewController.h
-------------------------------
@interface ParameterListerViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
{    
    UIScrollView* scrollView;
}
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger numberOfParameters;
@end
```

Here's the header file which contains the UIButton and the respective target method which contains the code for pushing the navigation controller.

```
SettingsViewController.h
------------------------
@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{   
    id <SettingsViewDelegate> delegate;
}
@end
```

And here's the header file of a class object that DOES GET PUSHED:

```
@interface ItemViewController : UITableViewController 
{
}
@end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you trying to push a navigation controller on top of another?

Comment: Try `self.navigationController pushViewController:plvc animated:YES`

Comment: Unfortunately this crashes as well. I forgot to mention that I tried pushing `plvc` earlier. I created a whole new project (just to make sure it is not one of those 'mystery' bugs) and still it doesn't work.  I added some more details to the question.

Comment: What's in the console when it crashes?

Comment: Without seeing your crash log / console output it is going to be hard to help you. From previous experience, another possible cause is that your main view is not setup properly in your NIB file. Make sure the view outlet is connected to the file owner and that the file owner is setup as your view controller class `ParameterListerViewController`. If this is the case, you should see an error in the console anyway.

Comment: You still should not be pushing a navigation controller on top of another.

Comment: Guys! I didn't use a NIB and loaded all my UI elements through `loadView`. I somehow missed the statement [super loadView] and it messed up everything else. There was an infinite loop of calls to the `loadView` method in `ParameterListerViewController` and that was also the log output. @Rog could you please post your comment as an answer? I also made a mistake while trying to push `nvc` and not `plvc`. I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Ravi this question is probably best if deleted as there wasn't a problem in the first place. Well, there was, but not related to the question you are asking :)

Answer (score 0):

Your nav controller's view has to be in the view hierarchy.
Unless the nav controller is set as the rootViewController of a UIWindow, it needs to be explicitly added.

Try this:

```
    [self.view addSubview:self.nvc.view];
```

If this is the case, you won't need to do the pushViewController - the plvc will already be visible.

Comment: What you say is correct but it's not the answer to his question.  His mistake is he is pushing a UINavigationController instead of a UIViewController.  Rog's comment is the correct answer.

Comment: Rog's answer will only partially solve this, since the OP's nav controller view is still not in the view hierarchy. (It doesn't appear to be the rootViewController of a window, so it's just hanging there, undisplayed.)

Comment: @Rayfleck : This does not work. My nav controller is the rootViewController of the UIWindow, so I don't need to add any subviews. I have updated my question with more details pertinent. Help?

Comment: Ok, that was not clear.  When you try to push plvc, what happens? What error do you get?

Comment: I missed [super loadView] in plvc and that messed up everything!